# sockaddr and IPv6 address

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am just trying to understand getaddrinfo() behavior.

```
int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
                const struct addrinfo *hints,
                struct addrinfo **res);
```

Resulting IP(v4/v6) addresses data saved in (each) struct addrinfo.

```
struct addrinfo {
    int              ai_flags;
    int              ai_family;
    int              ai_socktype;
    int              ai_protocol;
    socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    char            *ai_canonname;
    struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};


struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

If one of the result is an IPv6 address (16 bytes), how can it be saved in ai_addr which is of type sockaddr whose size is < IPv6 address.

My issue here is that, I am type casting ai_addr to sockaddr_storage

```
(struct sockaddr_storage *)(res->ai_addr)
```

And end up in gcc warning:

> warning: cast increases required alignment of target type

What is the correct way to typecast sockaddr to sockaddr_storage?

Update after few answers:

Question was on gcc warning:

```
> warning: cast increases required alignment of target type
```

And it is resolved with:

```
(struct sockaddr_storage *)(void *)(res->ai_addr)
```

Comment: Hope you've read this its everything i've ever needed to know http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#lowlevel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ai_addr` is just a pointer. Depending on `ai_family`, the actual structure behind `ai_addr` differs:

- if `ai_family` is `AF_INET`, it's really a pointer to a `sockaddr_in` struct.
- if `ai_family` is `AF_INET6`, it's a pointer to a `sockaddr_in6` structure.

Due to the structure of `sockaddr_in`, `sockaddr_in6` and `sockaddr_storage` (http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html), you could cast the pointer to the actual structure depending on `ai_family` as described above.

Comment: `AF_INET` uses `sockaddr_in`, not `sockaddr`. It just happens that `sockaddr` and `sockaddr_in` have the same byte size for historic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using sockaddr_storage as the socket type since it is big enough for both IPv4 and IPv6 and can be cast to sockaddr

```
struct sockaddr_storage {
    sa_family_t  ss_family;     // address family

    // all this is padding, implementation specific, ignore it:
    char      __ss_pad1[_SS_PAD1SIZE];
    int64_t   __ss_align;
    char      __ss_pad2[_SS_PAD2SIZE];
};
```